# CSS alignment issues Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css

We just released an alpha version of a new web app, and for some reason the login box is never centered correctly in Internet Explorer. (Firefox/Chrome work).

Example: http://demo.ionfish.org/status2/core/admin/

CSS:

http://demo.ionfish.org/status2/css-fail.txt

I have a feeling that something is overriding the CSS for centering somewhere but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where–and *what*–is your doctype? The page is being rendered in quirks mode because you didn't specify anything.

In a recent version of IE, load your page and hit F12 to open the [developer tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Along the top of the window/panel, you'll see "Browser Mode: [something] Document Mode: [something]" Click the Document Mode section, and select any of the "standards" options to change the rendering behavior, and you should see your expected results. To actually make the browser do that on its *own*, though, you need to include a proper doctype.